# Multiple networks with single MIMO card

Tags: networking, network-interface

Is it possible to connect to multiple networks using a single mimo card?. Eg. I have a 2x2 mimo card, can i segregate it into 2x 1x1 and connecto to 2 different networks (basicaly, can i set the spacial stream 1 to connect to no network 1 and spacial stream 2 to connect to network 2)?

I have already investigated this topic, and i found that spatial streams are ganged together, so it is not possible. I also also found that i can be connected to 2 different networks, but both networks must use the same channel, and that not what i'm looking for...

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, i believe that it works in 2 spatial streams for performance reasons.